# print images from a folder in vb .net with 8 images per page

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, picturebox

i select a folder using vb .net.my code is like below--

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath

    End If
End Sub
```

But the problem is i don't have any idea about displaying the images(8 images Per page)

Comment: Do you have your `page` code? You need to have 8 picture boxes and simply replace them with the new images when user changes the `page`. Once you have your page, things will get a lot easier.

Comment: sorry i don't have page code.

Comment: you have form right? the `form` is your `page` (unless you have smaller control like `Panel` in the `form`) simply put 8 `PictureBox`es in your `Form` and two buttons `Prev Page` and `Next Page`. Then trace which `page` you are in by `int index`. Based on the `index`, you could load the pictures to be put in the 8 `PictureBox`es correctly according to what the user input is (they are: `Next Page` click or `Prev Page` click)

Comment: yeah i do have a form.but my requirement is i will select a folder that has some images. after a certain button is clicked it will generate a print preview with 8 pictures per page(4 images per row,legal paper size).i am a newbie learning myself. thanks

Comment: Then you may first need to create another form (apart from the main form) which you call when the user load a folder. In that form you create 8 PictureBoxes with all the buttons which I mention to create a print preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VB.Net Version:**

1. Since you want to create print preview, I would suggest you to create a new `Form` just for the print preview and track the `PageNumber` which the user inputs

   ```
   Dim pageNumber As Integer = 0 'start from 0, but change this according to the user input accordingly
   ```
2. You could get the list of files from the given folder by using `Directory.GetFiles` in the `System.IO`

   ```
   Dim rawpaths As List(Of String) = Directory.GetFiles(folder).ToList() 'This gets all files, not only images
   ```
3. You may need to provide a list of acceptable image extension according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx).

   ```
   Dim validImageFormat As New List(Of String) From {"jpg", "bmp", "png", "jpeg", "gif", "tiff"}
   ```
4. And filter your file results such that they only contains acceptable image results like this (using `Split` method, `Contains`, etc...)

   ```
   Dim paths As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
   For Each rawpath As String In rawpaths
       Dim rawwords As String() = rawpath.Split(".") 'split the rawpath, the important is the last element, which is the file extension
       If (validImageFormat.Contains(rawwords(rawwords.Length - 1))) Then 'the rawpath is a valid image path
           paths.Add(rawpath) 'this is a valid image path
       End If
   Next
   ```
5. Then, in your print preview `Form` you may need to list your 8 `ListBox`es to ease you to control the display later as well as to handle the case where the number of the images are not multiplication of 8

   ```
   Dim pbList As List(Of PictureBox) = New List(Of PictureBox)
   Private Sub printPreviewForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       pbList.Add(PictureBox1) 'list your picture box will help you later
       pbList.Add(PictureBox2)
       pbList.Add(PictureBox3)
       pbList.Add(PictureBox4)
       pbList.Add(PictureBox5)
       pbList.Add(PictureBox6)
       pbList.Add(PictureBox7)
       pbList.Add(PictureBox8)
   End Sub
   ```
6. Then, you need to determine, how many pictures are to be shown (min of 1, max of 8, based on the `PageNumber`)

   ```
   If (pageNumber * 8 > paths.Count) Then 'exceeds the possible image display
       Return 'this is not allowed, do something
   End If
   Dim minPathNo As Integer = pageNumber * 8 'get the min and max for later display
   Dim maxPathNo As Integer = Math.Min(pageNumber * 8 + 7, paths.Count - 1)
   ```
7. Finally, to display, you can use `Image.FromFile()` method to load the image file from your folder plus using the `minPathNo` and `maxPathNo` declared before to show the images safely

   ```
   If (pageNumber * 8 > paths.Count) Then 'exceeds the possible image display
       Return 'this is not allowed, do something
   End If
   Dim minPathNo As Integer = pageNumber * 8
   Dim maxPathNo As Integer = Math.Min(pageNumber * 8 + 7, paths.Count - 1)
   For i As Integer = minPathNo To minPathNo + 7
       Dim pbIndex As Integer = i - minPathNo
       If i <= maxPathNo Then
           pbList(pbIndex).Image = Image.FromFile(paths(i)) 'display existing image
       Else
           pbList(pbIndex).Image = Nothing 'don't display non-existing image
       End If
   Next
   ```

Edit:

Suppose your form looks like this:

[image]

Then this is how your code would look like in just one form. In your case, you have to make two forms:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Dim folder As String = "C:\MyPics"
    Dim validImageFormat As New List(Of String) From {"jpg", "bmp", "png", "jpeg", "gif", "tiff"}
    Dim pbList As List(Of PictureBox) = New List(Of PictureBox)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rawpaths As List(Of String) = Directory.GetFiles(folder).ToList() 'Assuming all the file is image
        Dim paths As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        For Each rawpath As String In rawpaths
            Dim rawwords As String() = rawpath.Split(".") 'split the rawpath, the important is the last element, which is the file extension
            If (validImageFormat.Contains(rawwords(rawwords.Length - 1))) Then 'the rawpath is a valid image path
                paths.Add(rawpath) 'this is a valid image path
            End If
        Next

        Dim pageNumber As Integer = NumericUpDown1.Value
        If (pageNumber * 8 > paths.Count) Then 'exceeds the possible image display
            Return 'this is not allowed, do something
        End If
        Dim minPathNo As Integer = pageNumber * 8
        Dim maxPathNo As Integer = Math.Min(pageNumber * 8 + 7, paths.Count - 1)
        For i As Integer = minPathNo To maxPathNo
            Dim currentPictureBox As Integer = i - minPathNo
            pbList(currentPictureBox).Image = Image.FromFile(paths(i))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        pbList.Add(PictureBox1)
        pbList.Add(PictureBox2)
        pbList.Add(PictureBox3)
        pbList.Add(PictureBox4)
        pbList.Add(PictureBox5)
        pbList.Add(PictureBox6)
        pbList.Add(PictureBox7)
        pbList.Add(PictureBox8)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And you only need to change the `numericUpDown` (simulating your page` to 0, 1, 2, etc...)

Comment: in form1 i browsed the folder and selected then loaded form2 with desgned tools as you said then i added the code below:

Comment: Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     List<Image> listImages = new List<Image>()
        listImages.Add(imageFromFolder)
     pictureBox0.Image = listImages[pageNumber * 8]
     pictureBox1.Image = listImages[pageNumber * 8 + 1]
     pictureBox2.Image = listImages[pageNumber * 8 + 2]
     pictureBox3.Image = listImages[pageNumber * 8 + 3]
     pictureBox4.Image = listImages[pageNumber * 8 + 4]

   ---------- i got errors. sorry for my ignorance i  beginner trying heart n soul


    End Sub

Comment: @Jannat I have updated the code example for VB.Net version. Use it instead of the C# version

Comment: thanks for your help.In the mean time i did some coding. would you look at   my code??[link ] http://pastebin.com/F30fXT1c

Comment: yes i accept your idea i just did it the way i  can do it .thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jannat in your code you seem to do something strange.  For i As Integer = 0 To 7
                            Pics.Add(PictureBox1)
                            Pics.Add(PictureBox2)
                            Pics.Add(PictureBox3)
                            Pics.Add(PictureBox4)
                            Pics.Add(PictureBox5)
                            Pics.Add(PictureBox6)
                            Pics.Add(PictureBox7)
                            Pics.Add(PictureBox8)

Comment: You make a for loop and then you add the picture box multiple times. This is clearly wrong. :/

Comment: I understand, but what do you think you do in that `For` loop? `Pics` is a list, how many times do you think you add item to your `Pics`? 8 (from for loop) x 8 (number of add lines) = 64, is this not right? :/

Comment: o no.. :/ how to explain this... maybe I will just update my answer by putting everything in one form, then you can take a look on it again and split it to two forms, ok?

Comment: thanks a lot that's what i wanted actually.i was dumb because i have started learning vb a few weeks ago.